# A conditional probability problem with no joint probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are 4 different event, $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, and the probability are 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, and 0.7, respectively, but we don't know the joint probability of any of them.

Additionally, we already know that there must be exact 2 events occur among those 4.

Is the information given above enough to calculate $P(B|¬A)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Delete 'complicated' in the title.

Comment: Do you mean that, in all trials, exactly two of these must occur?  Or do you just mean that, in some particular trial we note that exactly two occured?  Or something else?

Comment: @lulu Yes. In all trials, exactly two of these must occur.

Comment: I suggest clarifying that point in the post, I don't think it is clear.

Comment: @Liding Yao Ok fine. I'll delete that word.

Comment: Note:  Suppose the event space consists of drawing an integer in $\{1, \cdots, 10\}$.  Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{7,8,9,10\}$, $C=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $D=\{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$.  Then, I believe, your condition is satisfied and $P(B\,|\,A^c)=\frac 47$.  So, that's the value *if it is determined*.  Of course, if you could exhibit another configuration with a different value, then we'd know it was not determined.

Comment: Hmm... If $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$, $B=\{3, 8, 9, 10\}$, $C=\{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, $D=\{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ then $P(B|A^c)=\frac{3}{7}$. So that might not be determined then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \textbf {Example I}$:  draw an integer uniformly from $\{1, \cdots, 10\}$.  Define our events as

$$A_1=\{1,2,3\}\quad B_1=\{7,8,9,10\} \quad C_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\quad D_1=\{4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$

We see that, as desired, each draw belongs to exactly two of your events, and we see that $P(B_1\,|\,A_1^c)=\frac 47$

$ \textbf {Example II}$:  Same process.  Now define
$$A_2=\{1,2,3\}\quad B_2=\{1,2,3,4\} \quad C_2=\{5,6,7,8,9,10\}\quad D_2=\{4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$

Again, one can verify that each draw is in exactly two events.  This time, however, $P(B_2\,|\,A_2^c)=\frac 17$

So it is not determined.